# killing intent (camera recording intent) during its activity

Tags: android, video, camera, android-intent, recording

Is it possible to cancel an intent during its activity ??
Because i launched camera intent ==> through "MediaStore" to record a video (and put it in a file.3gp) and just after taken the video, i could not return in my activity, the phone is locked on the camera Preview..
I think it is an inherant problem of my customized android version (overcome), so i want canceled the camera intent juste after the video recording but i dont know how ... ?
Help me please ..!!

Here is my code :

```
//create new Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    fileUri =  Uri.fromFile(new 

    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + 

    "/recordvideotestoutput.3gp"));
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0); // set the video image quality 

    to high
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 4000);   
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION, true); //====> normaly this 
     code shall return after video recording but it do not work...
    // start the Video Capture Intent

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have implemented `startActivityForResult` you need to implement `onActivityResult` method..